# Why can't I use "C-," to bind keys in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've used keybindings that start with "C-," in many other major modes and they all work. But it does not seem to work in org-mode (I tried to bind "C-, C-d" to `org-deadline`).

This is how I bind keys:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-, C-d") 'org-deadline)))
```

It looks like if I change it to

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'org-deadline)))
```

then the binding works. However, it is still unclear to me how to bind "C-, C-d". And the first way of binding works in other major modes (Latex, Python, etc...) I use.

Comment: You do not show anything that you tried. How did you try to bind that key sequence?

Comment: For me, `C-,` already has a local binding in `org-mode`. Did you remove that? Because otherwise you're trying to use a non-prefix binding as a prefix.

Comment: For clarification just in case anyone else is confused, it looks like the original is interested in using the control key plus the comma key as a keyboard prefix binding -- i.e., the original poster is not using the comma in the English grammar sense.

Comment: @phils What binding? Maybe that's the problem. I have several global keybindings with prefix `C-,` and they can override any local bindings introduced by other modes.

Comment: Global bindings have the *lowest* priority of all. Major mode keymaps take precedence over the global map, and minor mode keymaps take precedence over major mode maps. (There are more types, but the priorities of these three are the most important ones.)

Comment: You can ask Emacs what `C-,` is bound to by typing `C-h k C-,` in an org-mode buffer. You can remove the binding using `(eval-after-load "org" '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-,") nil))`

Comment: @phils I use a minor mode to define global bindings (a minor mode called "my-keys" that can override any other bindings).

Comment: user69818: Those aren't global bindings, then. "global" has a very specific meaning when it comes to Emacs keymaps. Referring to a minor mode keymap as "global" is tremendously misleading.

Comment: However your minor mode wouldn't be relevant here. `local-set-key` in this context will attempt to bind a key sequence in `org-mode-map`, and as mentioned there is already a non-prefix binding for `C-,` in that keymap.

Comment: @phils Why my minor mode is not relevant? I tried `describe-key` "C-," under ord-mode, but nothing happens.

Comment: Because you're not creating the keybinding in your minor mode's map; you're using `local-set-key` which will use the major mode's keymap. Elaborate on "nothing happens" please, because *something* should happen (either a help buffer describing the binding, or a message in the echo area telling you there's no binding for that key sequence).

Comment: @phils It just regards "C-," as a prefix and waits for me to type the next key. But I found out that that's indeed due to my minor mode. After I turn off my minor mode, it shows that "C-," is bound to `org-cycle-agenda-files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`local-set-key` in this context will attempt to bind a key sequence in `org-mode-map`, and there is already a non-prefix binding for `C-,` in that keymap, so you can't then create a binding in the same keymap which treats `C-,` as a prefix.

n.b. You can ask Emacs what `C-,` is bound to by typing `C-h k C-,` in an org-mode buffer.

You can remove the default binding using:

```el
(eval-after-load "org" '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-,") nil))
```

(after which you would be able to execute your original code.)